# Delete file after download

Tags: powershell

First of all my apologies if this is not the best place to ask this but I would like to know how could be a file, after being download and executed, automatcaly being deleted, in powershell

Thanks

Comment: I do not think this can be natively accomplished. You download a file, then action a file (next step) and so it is unlikely you can automatically and natively delete a file after taking action on the file.

Comment: PowerShell or any other language has no idea if you downloaded and ran a file unless you tell it to watch for that. You need to write your own code to do this. Writhe code to 1 - download the file, 2 - run file/code, 3 - check for exit code for success, if successful, delete the file.